# UWP HRESULT E_FAIL Error when setting a XAML Page's RequestedTheme

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am trying to programmatically set an invidivual XAML view's RequestedTheme. I'm doing this in order to get pages to update accent color, see [this](https://xamlbrewer.wordpress.com/2017/02/22/using-a-dynamic-system-accent-color-in-uwp/) article for explanation.

The problem is that if I try to set the Page's requested theme in code it throws an "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component".

Here is the code for one of my page's constructor:

```
public Dashboard()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.RequestedTheme = ElementTheme.Light;
}
```

Ideally the requested theme will be set by a a User's stored preference, and I did have that there initially, but even with a hard-coded ElementTheme value it throws the error.

Thing is, this works perfectly fine on my W10M phone. No errors, themes update correctly, accent color updates, everything works how it should.

But it always gives this error and crashes on my desktop.

Comment: Does this reproduce for you also with an empty Page, or only with your Dashboard page? Asking because in my testing it worked fine for an empty page, so I am wondering what I am missing to reproduce this. Thanks!

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT It did not occur on an empty page. After a lot of trial and error and manually checking with each xaml element I found the issue. This was caused by the Template 10 Pageheader control having a ThemeResource set in a resource dictionary. I'm not sure why this causes an exception, but when the ThemeResource is removed or switched to a StaticResource it works fine. Still kinda weird cause this wasn't an issue at all on my windows phone, just the desktop.